# Change Button Style dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles

I have defined two different styles in a ResourceDictionary as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="EditButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource BrushBlueSelector}" Padding="5,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Turquoise" BlurRadius="8" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Path x:Name="buttonSymbol" Data="M0,44.439791L18.98951,54.569246 0.47998798,62.66881z M17.428029,12.359973L36.955557,23.568769 21.957478,49.686174 20.847757,46.346189 15.11851,45.756407 14.138656,42.166935 8.5292659,41.966761 6.9493899,38.037481 2.4399572,38.477377z M26.812517,0.0009765625C27.350616,-0.012230873,27.875986,0.10826397,28.348372,0.3782568L42.175028,8.3180408C43.85462,9.2780154,44.234529,11.777948,43.02482,13.89789L41.375219,16.767812 21.460039,5.3381228 23.10964,2.4582005C23.979116,0.941679,25.437378,0.034730911,26.812517,0.0009765625z" 
                          Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="24" Height="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushOrangeSelector}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Orange" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushHeaderBackground}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Gray" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Gray" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="EditButton" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />

</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="SaveButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource BrushBlueSelector}" Padding="5,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Turquoise" BlurRadius="2" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Path x:Name="buttonSymbol" Data="M8.1099597,36.94997L8.1099597,41.793968 39.213959,41.793968 39.213959,36.94997z M12.42,0.049999889L18.4,0.049999889 18.4,12.252 12.42,12.252z M0,0L7.9001866,0 7.9001866,14.64218 39.210766,14.64218 39.210766,0 47.401001,0 47.401001,47.917 0,47.917z" 
                          Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="24" Height="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Green" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushHeaderBackground}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Gray" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="SaveButton" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />

</Style>
```

I have an edit button inside dataGrid as follows:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Margin="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Width="*" Header="Names"/>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource EditButton}" Click="EditButton_InsideDataGrid_Click" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

And here is it's click event:

```
private void EditButton_InsideDataGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    string tagValue = String.Empty;

    if (button != null)
    {
        tagValue = button.Tag.ToString();

        if (tagValue == "EditButton")
        {
            button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["SaveButton"];
        }
        else if (tagValue == "SaveButton")
        {
            button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["EditButton"];
        }
    }        
}
```

Now, it works fine. I can see that:

```
Initially      : Style is EditButton.
Click 1st time : Style is SaveButton.
Click 2nd time : Style is EditButton.
Click 3rd time : Style is SaveButton.
Click 4th time : Style is EditButton.
Click 5th time : Style is SaveButton.
......
......
......
```

Now, when I add the below mentioned code in Click event of the editButton :

```
    int colIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;

    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
    while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridCell))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    if (dep is DataGridCell)
    {

        colIndex = ((DataGridCell)dep).Column.DisplayIndex;

        while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridRow))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dep;
        rowIndex = FindRowIndex(row);
    }

    while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGrid))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)dep;

    for (int column = 0; column < colIndex; column++)
    {
        if (!(dg.Columns[column].IsReadOnly))
        {
            DataGridCell cell = GetDataGridCell(new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[column]));
            //cell.IsEditing = true;
        }
    }

    dg.BeginEdit();

}

public DataGridCell GetDataGridCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
{
    var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
    if (cellContent != null)
        return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;

    return null;
}

private int FindRowIndex(DataGridRow row)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(row) as DataGrid;

    int index = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row);

    return index;
}
```

Now, my results are:

```
Initially      : Style is EditButton.
Click 1st time : Style is EditButton.
Click 2nd time : Style is SaveButton.
Click 3rd time : Style is EditButton.
Click 4th time : Style is SaveButton.
Click 5th time : Style is EditButton.
......
......
......
```

Here is the sample project in which I reproduced the same problem:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0beVJXTG5yWTZwZm8/view?usp=sharing

**Update:**

New Sample as Suggested by @Yoyo : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bUGxRRklDOUpKRms/view?usp=sharing

I have tried to follow @Yoyo's instructions successfully. But still the problem remains same.

Comment: It is not very common way how to solve this type of action. It is very ugly and not simple solution. Try to create your custom button  and create dependency property e.g. Mode=Edit/Save and in some triggers or storyboards you can change only values that you want. Not style of whole button.

Comment: @YoYo I successfully implemented your idea. But still the problem remains same. Here is the new sample : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bUGxRRklDOUpKRms/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I offer to solve your issue

I rewrite your style for button

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       x:Key="EditSaveStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Brush x:Key="BrushHeaderBackground">#FF2A2A2A</Brush>
        <Brush x:Key="BrushBlueSelector">#FF0094FF</Brush>
        <Brush x:Key="BrushOrangeSelector">#FFFF6A00</Brush>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource BrushOrangeSelector}" />
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StreamGeometry>
                M0,44.439791L18.98951,54.569246 0.47998798,62.66881z M17.428029,12.359973L36.955557,23.568769 21.957478,49.686174 20.847757,46.346189 15.11851,45.756407 14.138656,42.166935 8.5292659,41.966761 6.9493899,38.037481 2.4399572,38.477377z M26.812517,0.0009765625C27.350616,-0.012230873,27.875986,0.10826397,28.348372,0.3782568L42.175028,8.3180408C43.85462,9.2780154,44.234529,11.777948,43.02482,13.89789L41.375219,16.767812 21.460039,5.3381228 23.10964,2.4582005C23.979116,0.941679,25.437378,0.034730911,26.812517,0.0009765625z
            </StreamGeometry>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Background="{StaticResource BrushBlueSelector}"
                        Padding="5,2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        CornerRadius="3">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                          Color="Turquoise"
                                          BlurRadius="8" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Path x:Name="buttonSymbol"
                          Data="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          Stretch="Uniform"
                          Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
                          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1"
                                                    ScaleY="1" />
                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                                  Color="{Binding Background.Color,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                  BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource BrushHeaderBackground}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                                  Color="Gray"
                                                  BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="Gray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                                                  Color="Gray"
                                                  BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"
                     Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <StreamGeometry>M8.1099597,36.94997L8.1099597,41.793968 39.213959,41.793968 39.213959,36.94997z M12.42,0.049999889L18.4,0.049999889 18.4,12.252 12.42,12.252z M0,0L7.9001866,0 7.9001866,14.64218 39.210766,14.64218 39.210766,0 47.401001,0 47.401001,47.917 0,47.917z</StreamGeometry>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

- the style is based on standard button instead
- I combined both templates and specified the difference in the trigger
- The trigger is based on the parent `DataGridRow.IsEditing`

here is the rewrite of the code in main window.cs

```
private void EditButton_InsideDataGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    int colIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;

    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
    while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridCell))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;
    DataGridRow row = null;
    if (dep is DataGridCell)
    {

        colIndex = ((DataGridCell)dep).Column.DisplayIndex;

        while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridRow))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        row = (DataGridRow)dep;
        rowIndex = FindRowIndex(row);

    }

    while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGrid))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)dep;
    if (row != null)
    {
        if (row.IsEditing)
            dg.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
        else
        {
            dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[rowIndex], dg.Columns[0]);
            dg.BeginEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

I did some adjustments to edit and save a row.

finally the data grid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Margin="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
            CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Width="*" Header="Names"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Click="EditButton_InsideDataGrid_Click"
                            Style="{StaticResource EditSaveStyle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have use the style `EditSaveStyle` on a standard button

using this approach you may not required to inherit and create your own button for switching style etc. you may perhaps introduce attached properties if you look forward to customize even more.

here is a working sample [ChangingStylesAtRuntime.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPX21MVUVOMF90aW8/view?usp=sharing)

note that `dg.CommitEdit` may fail if the data is not properly binded or `IsReadOnly="True"` is not set for un-bound/read-only columns

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement your answer in my sample project as well as in my real project. I got a difference in both the projects. In my sample project everything runs fine. But in my real project, I cannot see any Icon like pencil or floppy on the button. Can you tell me the problem.

Comment: @Vishal, do you still have the missing icon issue? missing icon may be due to the content set in the button itself as style can not override the local values. so remove any content from the buttons eg `<Button Content="content"/>` or `<Button>content</Button>`. if problem still persist I may need to see the actual implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I never looked at the Button's Content. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a DataTemplateSelector Class.

This class provides a way to choose a DataTemplate based on the data object and the data-bound element.

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
...
<local:TaskListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>   
...

</Window.Resources>
...
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

**Class:**

```
public class TaskListDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is Task)
        {
            Task taskitem = item as Task;

            if (taskitem.Priority == 1)
                return
                    element.FindResource("importantTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else 
                return
                    element.FindResource("myTaskTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: As you described here that DataTemplateSelector provides a way to choose a DataTemplate based on the data object and the data-bound collection. But if you look back at my question, I don't want to change the Template of DataGridRows. I just want to change the ControlTemplate of a button inside dataGrid. When button is initialized it gets a ControlTemplate of Edit Button. When the user clicks on it, the ControlTemplate of that button should be switched to Save Button. And again Edit Button on click and so on....... Thanks for your try.